# What is this connector called and where can I buy it? Cooler Master Notepal U3 Fan connection broke

Tags: usb, hardware-failure, connector

I have the Cooler Master Notepal U3 cooling pad for my laptop but the usb connector is broke :(. This means that I can't use the fans beneath for cooling. I don't feel like buying a new pad cause of this.

[image: The cable]

[image: Close up of the part]

[image: The conector]

Any advice on what I need to buy?

Comment: Its not called anything.  We don't have the PCB diagram, so we can't even tell you what wires are connect to what.  Why don't you just buy a new one?  I can guarantee you it would be cheaper then trying to build yourself a new wire.  Contact Cooler Master they might be able to replace the cable for you at little to no cost.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, I have written them but they are not responding. It can't be impossible to fix it by myself.